How do you find how long an object will take to travel to a specific point in a planets sphere of influence?
So I haven't been able to find a solution to this:
Let's say there is an asteroid the will travel through Earth's SOI. We know the object's periapsis in Earth's SOI and its speed relative to Earth when it enters Earth's SOI.
How can I calculate how long it would take for the asteroid to reach a specific point along its trajectory and how fast it is going?
PS I'm a pretty new to this kind of stuff and I understand the basics.

Ah, overloaded three letter acronyms... Clearly SOI is not silicon-on-insulator here.

SOI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_of_influence_(astrodynamics)

Not sure it merits a full answer, but this is a problem of basic orbital mechanics. Find the total energy at SOI entry, take out the potential energy at the given point, and you have the kinetic energy at the given point.

It's not clear what you mean by "the object's periapsis in Earth's SOI". Is that the asteroid's perigee, or is it its perihelion in a reference frame where the Earth is at the origin?

BTW, you may like to browse related questions on our sister site, eg https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soi

What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Once the position and velocity is known, the conic section trajectory is uniquely determined.


How do you find how long an object will take to travel to a specific point in a planets sphere of influence ?

Without more specific details, it is difficult to give a more precise answer than "use orbital mechanics". We know the gravitational forces acting on the asteroid - and, if it close to the Earth, it may be sufficient to only consider the Earth, the Moon and the Sun and ignore the other planets. If we know its position and velocity at a given point in time then we can in principle extrapolate forward to find its position and velocity at any future time. Almost certainly this will require the use of numerical methods - it is very unlikely that there will be a closed form analytical solution into which you can plug a time and get out a position and velocity.
In practice, the problems in predicting the trajectories of near-earth asteroids lie not in applying orbital mechanics, but are (a) detecting a small dim object in the first place and (b) finding the distance to a small dim object with sufficient precision to usefully apply orbital mechanics.
